# Turning a string from a text file into the name of a variable

Tags: python

I have a players class with a bunch of different players, one of them being players.mike

I have a team class with five different players. I don't want to define these players in the .py file, as I want to be able to switch players in the team some time later in the game.

The player I currently want as team.player1 is players.mike. The only way I know how to do this is with a .txt file, i.e. player1.txt, which reads

```py
'players.mike'
```

To get the contents of the .txt into the script I have a simple var_get function which returns the contents of a file.

I want to be able to define team.player1 like this:

```py
team.player1 = var_get('player1.txt')
```

This way, should I want player1 to be randomly chosen later on in the game, I can have the program pick a random player and write it to player1.txt.

The only issue is that var_get can only return strings, since it is pulling from a .txt file.

Is there a way that I can turn the strings I get from the .txt file into the name of a variable, so instead of getting

```py
team.player1 = 'players.mike'
```

I get

```py
team.player1 = players.mike
```

Comment: use dictionary, creating dynamic variable is bad practice.

Comment: Does that mean you have already defined the `Team` and `Player` classes in your python code, and you want to create a new object of `Team` or `Player` by giving the name?

Comment: Logically it is incorrect because the python variable must be defined before it used on RHS. in your case players.mike should be declared and define with some default value before it is used.

Comment: in python its possible to define dynamic variables @Mr.J , but you should no use it

Comment: yeah, I know, but I certainly, disagree with the listed scenario.

Comment: @Nihal Thank you so much. I've been pulling my hair out  all day trying to come up with a solution. What I did was create a dictionary playerdict (after figuring out how dictionaries work), and set integer keys equal to players, i.e. playerdict{1:players.mike,2:players.kyle,etc.}. Now I just pull the key from players.txt and it works like a charm.